# PySide6 - How to validate and reject Intermediate input with QIntValidator in a QLineEdit?

Tags: python, validation, if-statement, pyside, edit

I'm trying to set range for a QLineEdit using QIntValidator(2,100). It works in the way that when number is in the range of 2 to 100 it returns QValidateState = Acceptable. When number is out of range it should return QValidateState = Intermediate. But in case of Intermediate it still accepts input. In case of letters it returns Invalid, so user can't put letters in QLineEdit.

```
        self.validator = QIntValidator(2, 100)
        self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.setValidator(self.validator)
        self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.somefunc)
```

Well, i've tried to add a condition so it doesn't accept Intermediate input:
First attempt:

```
            if self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.hasAcceptableInput:
                print('SHIIIIIIIIET')
            else:
                self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.setText('42')
```

Second attempt:

```
    def somefunc(self):
            if self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.hasAcceptableInput:
                print('SHIIIIIIIIET')
            elif not self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.hasAcceptableInput:
                self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.setText('42')
```

Third attempt:

```
    def somefunc(self):
            value = self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.text()
            if self.validator.validate(value, 0)[0] == QValidator.Acceptable:
                self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.setText('42')
                print('SHIIIIIIIIET')
            elif self.validator.validate(value, 0)[0] == QValidator.Intermediate or self.validator.validate(value, 0)[0] == QValidator.Invalid: 
                self.ui.StepsAmountLineEdit.setText('42')
                print('WOW')
```

In all cases it works at first condition, when state is Acceptable. But it doesn't work when it isn't Acceptable.

Comment: You're missing the parentheses in `hasAcceptableInput`. Also, avoid profanity, it's really unnecessary, just use appropriate names for objects and useful string values.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks you very much for answering! I'm sorry about profanity in the suggested code, i just was very tired of this issue when was writing this post. So, no parentheses is pretty much accepted in condition, so it wasn't the issue. But i found the main reason of it! The thing is for some reason if i put range in QIntValidator, it blocks any other attempts  of validation through if-statements or anything. So i've gotten rid of range from it and everything worked as it should!